# I want to fetch user contact number when click "Show Number" button in WordPress through code

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I designed WordPress site but I'm stuck in contact number show functionality
In my site 2 different role users 1. Teacher 2. Student
I have fetch all users(teacher role) from database and showing as a card view in page.
But the teacher contact number needs to hide and when student access page and click "View Mobile Number" then number will be show from database in page via AJAX.

Student need to purchase credit points and then student can view 1 teacher number by using 1 credit point

My code to showing Teachers Fetch from database and showing in page via PHP Snippet in WordPeress

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'role'    => 'teacher',
    'orderby' => 'user_login',
    'order'   => 'ASC'
);
$users = get_users( $args );

echo '<div class="outer-box">';
foreach ( $users as $user ) {
    $stdnm = $user->first_name; // Parent/Student Name-
    $addr = $user->Location; // Address-
    $phno = $user->phone_number; // Contact No
    $eml = $user->user_email; // Email
    $cls = $user->uclass; // Student Class-
    $board = $user->board; // Student Board-
    $subject = $user->u_Subjects; // Student Subject-
    $days_week = $user->s_day_available; // Days a week-
    $a_days_week = $user->s_days_a_week; // Days a week-
    $hrs_day = $user->hrs_days; // hrs a day-
    $d_available = $user->s_day_available; // Day's Available -
    $t_from = $user->time_available_from; // Time Available From-
    $t_to = $user->time_available_to; // Time Available To-
?>
    <div class="main-box">
        <div class="box-heading"><?php echo $stdnm; ?></div>
         <div class="desc-box">
            <div>Address - <?php echo $addr; ?></div>
            <div class="quali-exp">
                <div>Class - <?php echo $cls; ?></div>
                <div>|</div>
                <div class="experi">Board - <?php echo $board; ?></div>
            </div>
     
            <div>Subject - <?php echo $subject; ?></div>
              <div>Days week - <?php echo   $a_days_week; ?></div>

                <div>hrs a day - <?php echo $hrs_day; ?></div>
          <div>Day's Available -
            <?php
              $sub = $user->s_day_available;
              if( $sub): ?>
             <?php foreach( $sub as $ssub): ?>
             <?php echo "<span class='after-day'>" . $ssub . "</span>"; ?>
             <?php endforeach; ?>
             <?php endif; ?>
           </div>

           <div class="experi">Time Available - <?php echo $t_from; ?> - <?php echo $t_to; ?></div>
                        
           <div><button>View Mobile Number</button></div> // **I NEED ONLY THIS BUTTON WORKING TO FETCH CONTACT NUMBER FROM DATABASE**

         </div>
    </div>
<?php    
}
echo '</div>';
?>
```

[Here is a Output page screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2lDR.png)